# Very high xDB search indexer memory and out of memory crash

Tags: xdb, xconnect

Recently my xDB search indexer service (XConnectSearchIndexer.exe) has been using all the server RAM and half the CPU until it runs out of memory crashes. It restarts and immediately starts to consume all the memory again.

Any way of knowing what is causing the high CPU usage or any way to limit the memory consumption of the indexer service.

Sitecore 9.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to this article from Maarten Willebrands, the issue is that Sitecore, pre 9.3, is configured to try and index too many things at once. When 9.3 was released they lowered the number.

https://www.maartenwillebrands.nl/2021/01/22/xconnect-search-indexer-high-memory-usage/

The setting is the `SplitRecordsThreshold`  and it is located in the file C:<Path to xConnect>\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\Config\Sitecore\SearchIndexer\sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml

> Controls the limit for the number of records loaded into memory (per
> core) by the indexer at any one time.
>
> If the indexer is using too much memory, decrease this value.
>
> To disable splitting, set this value to 0, a negative value, or remove
> the element completely.

The default in 9.1, the setting is `25000`. But in 9.3+ the setting is `1000`. I changed the number it 1000 and the indexing proceeds at a controlled pace and no longer consumes all the memory of the server.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/configuring-the-xconnect-search-indexer.html